# golang: accessing value in slice of interfaces

Tags: go

I have a data structure which comes of out go-spew looking like this:

```
([]interface {}) (len=1 cap=1) {
 (string) (len=1938) "value"
}
```

It is of type `[]interface {}`

How can I print this `value` with `fmt`, or access it in some way so that I can use it.

Comment: What's the context? How do you want to use it? If you want to print it with `fmt`, [you can do that](https://play.golang.org/p/S0n2C0SJDY).

Comment: The problem is that it seems to return a slice (or something surrounding by [] at least). I tried to range over it, but got `cannot range over value (type interface {})`

Comment: and yes, I just want to assign it to something so I can `fmt` print in.

Comment: See answer for details...

Answer (score 1):

You can use type assertions or reflection work with the generic `interface{}` to an underlying type. How you do this depends on your particular use case. If you can expect the `interface{}` to be a `[]interface{}` as in your example, you can:

```
if sl, ok := thing.([]interface{}); ok {
    for _, val := range sl {
        fmt.Println(val)
        // Or if needed, coerce val to its underlying type, e.g. strVal := val.(string)
    }
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/D3PDxAd2Iw))

If you can't make assumptions about the underlying type, you'll need to do some black magic using [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/).